# CoreData one-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data

I've got a Food entity with a one-to-many relationship:

```
- (void)addIngredientsObject:(Ingredient *)value;
- (void)removeIngredientsObject:(Ingredient *)value;
- (void)addIngredients:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeIngredients:(NSSet *)values;
```

The Ingredient entity has:

```
@class Food;

@interface Ingredient : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * quantity;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * recordUUID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Food *foodItem;

@end
```

I consider a Food like a recipe, if there are items for Food.ingredients, it's a recipe, otherwise not.

Now when I try to add Ingredients to my (Food) recipe:

```
    Ingredient *recipeIngredient = [[Ingredient alloc] init];
recipeIngredient.foodItem = ingredient;
NSLog(@"ingredient: %@", ingredient.name);
recipeIngredient.quantity = q;

[addRecipeController.items addObject:recipeIngredient];
```

and

```
    recipe = [[Food alloc] init];

// Controllare che il nome sia univoco
recipe.name = nameTextField.text;

// Compute
for(Ingredient *ingredient in items) {
    [recipe addValuesFromFood:ingredient.foodItem withQuantity:ingredient.quantity];
    [recipe addIngredientsObject:ingredient];
}

// Defaults
recipe.bookmark = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
recipe.complex = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
recipe.dirty = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
recipe.lookback = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
recipe.userAdd = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

NSLog(@"pro: %f", recipe.pro.floatValue);
NSLog(@"items: %d", [recipe.ingredients count]);
```

it saves successfully.

But when I go into the details and try to check it out the ingredients of my recipe...

```
    NSMutableSet *foods = [item mutableSetValueForKey:@"ingredients"];
for(Ingredient *ing in foods) {
    NSLog(@"Class: %@", NSStringFromClass([ing.foodItem class]));
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", ing.foodItem.name);
}
```

I've got that all the ingredient's name are equal to the recipe ingredient... and that's wrong... If I try to log the names in this loop:

```
    // Compute
for(Ingredient *ingredient in items) {
    // NSLOG for food name here
    [recipe addValuesFromFood:ingredient.foodItem withQuantity:ingredient.quantity];
    [recipe addIngredientsObject:ingredient];
}
```

everything is right, but things go wrong after [recipe addIngredientsObject:ingredient]...

What's going on?! Cannot escape from this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed removing the inverse relationship from the one-to-many (Ingredients.foodItem)

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand fully what you are trying to do in your code, but there is one fundamental problem: Managed objects like `Food` and `Ingredient` must be properly initialized with `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`, you cannot just alloc+init them. (Well, you can, but it is more complicated.)

See for example [Creating, Initializing, and Saving a Managed Object](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001654-208209) in the *Core Data Programming Guide*.

Comment: I've got a category on Food and Ingredient... - (id)init
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
    
    self = [super initWithEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Food" inManagedObjectContext:context] insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
    
    if (self) {
    }
    
    return self;
}